# How can I use SVN on my hosted server to keep track of my php projects?

Tags: svn, repository

I write a lot of code from random projects but I never keep track of the version or changes. Ive used SVN enough that I feel like I should start keeping repositories of my code, but I dont know how to set it up or organize it for random projects.

Also can you use SVN to keep track of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subversion to manage any file type - it works great for images, in my experience.

The How-To section of the FAQ might be a good place to start learning about how to get it set up: https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html

If you find that it doesn't quite meet your needs, or you don't want to host your own revision control server, you might also want to look at git and github or mercurial.

Comment: thanks =] my web host has svn on it already so im going to try to use that...